# How to move points along the curve in Geo Nodes Blender 3.0

Tags: node-editor

I am creating a car traffic using geo nodes. Is there any way move these "cars" along the curve normal?[image: This is the current situation]

[image: This is the current Geo Nodes Setup]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this node setup for correct aligning:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!. But how can i make them move along the curve and having constant distances between them?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249144/animate-instance-points-on-a-curve-in-a-loop-geo-nodes maybe this setup helps